# Dual boot Android + Ubuntu on Nexus 4 (no sound & where to get apps?)

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-touch

I have installed ubuntu dual boot on Nexus 4, but mobile sound is not working when i boot my mobile with ubuntu. Also let me from where i can get applications for ubuntu.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For sound problem in dual boot you need to recheck all the steps [from the wiki in Touch/DualBootInstallation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation) and verify that.

To know about ubuntu-touch(mobile) applications, please [about the ecosystem:](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/app-ecosystem)

> Ubuntu mobile developers working closely with selected partners to get
>   their apps onto Ubuntu; Facebook, Twitter, Dropbox, Evernote and
>   Amazon will be available at launch, and also built an expanding set of
>   core native apps with our community. And with our API, thousands of
>   Ubuntu developers are taking up the challenge of building a single app
>   that works across web, desktop and mobile. [...]